# intellisense doesn't recognise classes

Tags: c++, object, intellisense

I was coding a small game, when i got an error from intelisense. I tried again with a simple pet class, but intellisense didn't think it was correct. here is the code and the errors:

```
#include <iostream>
class Pet{
public:
    int m_hunger;
    void Greet();
};
void Pet::Greet(){
    std::cout << "My hunger is " << m_hunger;
}
int main(){
    Pet dog();
    dog.m_hunger = 9;//Expression must have class type
    dog.Greet();//Expression must have class type
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend printing "\n" at the end of your output or using `std::endl`.  Both will flush the data in buffers to the standard output.

Answer (score 5):

`Pet dog();` does not create a `Pet`.  It creates a function named `dog` that returns a `Pet` and takes no parameters.

You can change it to `Pet dog;` which will create a `Pet` named `dog`.